Getting meta data error while migrating from the Play Core Java and Kotlin Library
Error:
Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.versionCode@value value=(20202) from AndroidManifest.xml:54:13-34
is also present at [com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1] AndroidManifest.xml:17:85-106 value=(10901).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.

I am receiving the following warning from the Google Play Console team:
com.google.android.play:core has added this note for core:1.10.3:
If your app is targeting SDK 34+ (targetSdkVersion), then the PlayCore SDK is outdated and will likely cause crashes in your app! Please update:
I start updating PlayCore following migrating instruction from : migration instructions
I followed the migration instructions and updated my app code. However, when I try to build the app, I encounter a conflict between two libraries, even though my build.gradle file does not include com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1.
I have tried implementing the suggested fix by adding tools:replace="android:value" to the  element in my AndroidManifest.xml, but the issue persists. Additionally, I removed the core library com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.10.3 as a prerequisite for migrating from the Java core library to the Kotlin library.
I also updated the imports in my activity class as per the migration instructions. Despite these efforts, the error and conflict remain unresolved. Here is my build.gradle file for reference:

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
   
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 34
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId ''
           minSdkVersion 28
           targetSdkVersion 34
           multiDexEnabled true
           versionCode 00
           versionName ""
           testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
               signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
           }
       }
       flavorDimensions "default"
       productFlavors {
           staging {
               applicationId ''
           }
           production {
               applicationId ''
           }
       }
   
       compileOptions {
           coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
           sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
           targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       }
       buildFeatures {
           viewBinding true
       }
       lint {
           abortOnError false
       }
   }
   
   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
       implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
       implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
       implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
       implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
       implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
   
       implementation("com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.2.2"){
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.play', module: 'core'
       }
       implementation("com.google.android.play:feature-delivery:2.1.0"){
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.play', module: 'core'
       }
       implementation("com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1"){
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.play', module: 'core'
       }
       implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3'
       implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1'
       implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
       implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0'
       implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:3.0.3'
       implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
       implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0' // TODO Upgrade to com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:2.0.0-alpha07
       implementation 'ca.antonious:materialdaypicker:0.5.0'
       implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:1.6.0'
       implementation 'com.github.franmontiel:AttributionPresenter:1.0.1'
       implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
       implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.6.1'
       implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.3.4'
       implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:2.0.3'
       implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.3.1'
       implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:1.35.5'
       implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:1.35.5'
       implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:6.2.2'
       implementation 'com.bugsee:bugsee-android:2.1.3'
       implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
   
       implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
   
       coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
   
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
       //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-rc01'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'
       implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.4.0'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.4.0'
       implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   
       implementation("androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0")
   }
   
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }




// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.  

~~~java
buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
   repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter()
       maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter()
       maven {
           url 'https://jitpack.io'
       }
       maven {
           url 'https://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
       }
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}






Can you share your build.gradle file?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@tomerpacific, I added my build.gradle file as requested and also add some more detail for your further understanding, Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

@AttaulJalil - It could be that one of your other dependencies is using play core as a dependency of their own.
